# While loop will not continue to ask the user for an input

Tags: java

I am very new to java and I need help. Basically, I have a program that asks the user to input a number. When the number is input, it takes a sum of all of the odd numbers before that number and adds them up. What I'm trying (and failing) to do is, make another loop whereby, when the user is prompted to ask for a number to sum up the odd numbers, I want to make it so that it will only continue when an odd number is entered, otherwise it will keep repeatedly asking the user until they enter an odd number. I know that using a `while` loop will solve this issue, but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddCalculator {
    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int number, i, oddSum = 0;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" Please Enter any Number : ");
        number = sc.nextInt();  
        while (number % 2 !=0) //HERE IS WHERE IM HAVING THE ISSUE
        {
            continue;
        }
        for(i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 != 0)
            {
                oddSum = oddSum + i; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n The Sum of Odd Numbers upto " + number + "  =  " + oddSum);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _asking the user until they enter an odd number_, you would probably have to reread the users input in the loop with `number = sc.nextInt();` instead of using `continue`.

Comment: I tried this but when I enter an invalid number the code just ends instead of asking the question again

Comment: Something to think about: What happens if the user does **not** enter a positive, whole number? For example -7 or 3.14

Answer (score 2):

`continue;` as a statement scans 'upwards and outwards' for the first construct that can be continued. Things that can be continued are currently only `for`, `while` and `do/while` statements, so it finds `while (number % 2 != 0)` and will continue it.

To continue a while loop means: Jump straight back to the condition `number %2 != 0`, evaluate it, and then enter the loop again if it is true, or hop to the `}` if it is false.

So, your code checks if the number is odd. If it is, it will .. continue. So, it will.. check if the number is odd. If it is, it will check if the number is odd. If it is, it will check if the number is odd.... forever.

Presumably your intent is to ask the user again, but then you'd have to wrap the loop around more code: Start with the `print`, because certainly `sc.nextInt()` needs to be *inside* the loop. That does mean you won't have a `number` value to check, but that's what do/while loops are for: To guarantee you loop at least once (and so that you can use anything calculated in the loop as part of the condition).

Comment: Thanks! I've now realised that, the while loop is applying to odd numbers which I need to make it so it applies to even numbers instead, and therefore if the number is even it will ask the user to input it again. My problem is how do you get the value to only check if the number entered is even in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should also use the scanner inside the `while` loop in case the number is not odd.

```
while (number % 2 !=0) {
    number = sc.nextInt(); // Use here as well to keep asking for a number until is odd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion seems to be coming from misunderstanding that `continue` means going back to the `while` loop, and `break` is what gets you out of the loop. Does this work for you?

```
System.out.println(" Please Enter any Number : ");
number = sc.nextInt();

// keep asking for a number for as long as it is even (condition is false on odd)
while (number % 2 == 0) {
   System.out.println("Please enter another number: ");
   number = sc.nextInt();
}

System.out.println(number + " is now odd!");
```

Comment: This is almost perfect but, when I try this and run it, when it says "Please enter another number" it does not give me the opportunity to enter another value, the program just stops running.

Comment: WAIT NO THIS WORKS, THANKS VERY MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this output is what you are looking for, the reason why your previous code doesn't work is that `number = sc.nextInt();` is the reason why you can prompt the user for an input, so you have to loop it, furthermore, you can give a specific prompt base on what the user has inputted in the if statement, hope this helps!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     // int number, i, oddSum = 0;
    int number, i, oddSum = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter any Number : ");
    do{
      number = sc.nextInt();
      if(number % 2 == 0){
        System.out.print("Please Enter an odd number!: ");
      }
    }while(number % 2 == 0);
    for(i = 1; i <= number; i++)
      {
          if(i % 2 != 0)
          {
              oddSum = oddSum + i; 
          }
      }
    System.out.println("\nThe Sum of Odd Numbers up to "  + number +   " = "  + oddSum);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Please Enter any Number : 2
Please Enter an odd number!: 2
Please Enter an odd number!: 3

The Sum of Odd Numbers up to 3 = 4
```

Comment: @dogwog1 hope this helps you, and if you like my solution do give an upvote and mark as a solution.